# Haskell function returning existential type

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Is it possible to write a Haskell function that yields a parameterised type where the exact type parameter is hidden? I.e. something like `f :: T -> (exists a. U a)`? The obvious attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data D a = D a

data Wrap = forall a. Wrap (D a)

unwrap :: Wrap -> D a
unwrap (Wrap d) = d
```

fails to compile with:

```
Couldn't match type `a1' with `a'
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a pattern with constructor
         Wrap :: forall a. D a -> Wrap,
       in an equation for `unwrap'
       at test.hs:8:9
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for unwrap :: Wrap -> D a at test.hs:7:11
Expected type: D a
  Actual type: D a1
In the expression: d
In an equation for `unwrap': unwrap (Wrap d) = d
```

I know this is a contrived example, but I'm curious if there is a way to convince GHC that I do not care for the exact type with which `D` is parameterised, without introducing another existential wrapper type for the result of `unwrap`.

To clarify, I do want type safety, but also would like to be able to apply a function `dToString :: D a -> String` that does not care about `a` (e.g. because it just extracts a String field from `D`) to the result of `unwrap`. I realise there are other ways of achieving it (e.g. defining `wrapToString (Wrap d) = dToString d`) but I'm more interested in whether there is a fundamental reason why such hiding under existential is not permitted.

Comment: I think the reason why `exists a. D a` is not a part of Haskell is a simple desire to avoid redundancy. This type is equivalent to `forall r. (forall a. D a -> r) -> r`, so one can just as well use that to represent existential values.

Comment: @n.m. while strictly speaking it's not equivalent, I agree that the only useful thing that can be done to such existential value is application of a function `forall a. D a -> r`, so inability to express this ad-hoc existential makes sense -- thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not in a straightforward way.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data D a = D a

data Wrap = forall a. Wrap (D a)

unwrap :: Wrap -> forall r. (forall a. D a -> r) -> r
unwrap (Wrap x) k = k x

test :: D a -> IO ()
test (D a) = putStrLn "Got a D something"

main = unwrap (Wrap (D 5)) test
```

You cannot return a `D something_unknown` from your function, but you can extract it and immediately pass it to another function that accepts `D a`, as shown.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can convince GHC that you do not care for the exact type with which `D` is parameterised. Just, it's a horrible idea.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Unsafe.Coerce

data D a = D a deriving (Show)

data Wrap where       -- this GADT is equivalent to your `ExistentialQuantification` version
   Wrap :: D a -> Wrap

unwrap :: Wrap -> D a
unwrap (Wrap (D a)) = D (unsafeCoerce a)

main = print (unwrap (Wrap $ D "bla") :: D Integer)
```

This is what happens when I execute that simple program:

[image]

and so on, until memory consumption brings down the system.

**Types are important!** If you circumvent the type system, you circumvent any predictability of your program (i.e. anything can happen, including [thermonuclear war](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-missiles/docs/Acme-Missiles.html#v:launchMissiles) or the famous [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

---

Now, evidently you thought that types somehow work differently. In dynamic languages such as Python, and also to a degree in OO languages like Java, a type is in a sense a *property* that a value can have. So, (reference-) values don't just carry around the information needed to distinguish different values *of a single type*, but also information to distinguish different (sub-)types. That's in many senses rather inefficient – it's a major reason why Python is so slow and Java needs such a huge VM.

In Haskell, types *don't exist* at runtime. A function never knows what type the values have it's working with. Only because the *compiler* knows all about the types it will have, the function doesn't *need* any such knowledge – the compiler has already hard-coded it! (That is, unless you circumvent it with `unsafeCoerce`, which as I demonstrated is as unsafe as it sounds.)

If you do want to attach the type as a “property” to a value, you need to do it explicitly, and that's what those existential wrappers are there for. However, there are usually better ways to do it in a functional language. What's really the application you wanted this for?

---

Perhaps it's also helpful to recall what a signature with polymorphic result means. `unwrap :: Wrap -> D a` doesn't mean “the result is some `D a`... and the caller better don't care for the `a` used”. That would be the case in Java, but it would be rather useless in Haskell because there's nothing you can do with a value of unknown type.

Instead it means: *for whatever* type `a` the caller requests, this function is able to supply a suitable `D a` value. Of course this is tough to deliver – without extra information it's just as impossible as doing anything with a value of given unknown type. But if there are already `a` values in the *arguments*, or `a` is somehow constrained to a type class (e.g. `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`, then it's quite possible and very useful.

---

To obtain a `String` field – independent of the `a` parameter – you can just operate directly on the wrapped value:

```
data D a = D
    { dLabel :: String
    , dValue :: a
    }

data Wrap where Wrap :: D a -> Wrap

labelFromWrap :: Wrap -> String
labelFromWrap (Wrap (D l _)) = l
```

To write such functions on `Wrap` more generically (with any “ label accesor that doesn't care about `a`”), use Rank2-polymorphism as shown in n.m.'s answer.

Comment: You don't have to circumvent the type system. Of course anything could happen if you do `unsafeCoerce`, but why do that?

Comment: @n.m. because the OP asked for it.

Comment: I don't see where OP asks about `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: Indeed, that's not what I was after. I've added a bit of clarification.

Comment: "there's nothing you can do with a value of unknown type." -- the type is not *completely* unknown, the compiler knows it's a `exists a. D a` so, as far as I understand, should be able to apply a function `forall a. (D a -> E)`

Comment: Please, never use `unsafeCoerce` when answering a Haskell question. It's not part of the language and should be avoided at almost any cost.

Comment: @augustss: that's why I said “you can _convince GHC_”, and demonstrated how it completely fails to be a solution here. — But then again, I think `unsafeCoerce` can actually be reasonable in Haskell answers (unlike `unsafePerformIO`): when it's about something where GHC can't confirm two types are equal, but you can actually prove it.

Comment: @leftroundabout I would never mention something as ugly and unsafe to someone who is obviously a beginner.

Comment: @augustss, `unsafeCoerce` is much less frightening than `unsafePerformIO`, IMO, and there's no other way to state useful postulates like `forall (a :: ()) . a :~: '()`. Of course, you're right anyway.

Comment: @dfeuer I mean they are equally frightening. If you have one you can define the other fairly easily: ``unsafeCoerce a = let r = unsafePerformIO (newIORef undefined) in unsafePeformIO (writeIORef r a) `seq` unsafePerformIO (readIORef r)``, and `unsafePerformIO a = runST $ unsafeCoerce a`.

Comment: @semicolon, well, the latter does rely on GHC representing `IO` and `ST` the same under the hood, while the former seems more portable. But what I really meant was that I think it's generally easier to reason about the safety requirements of *typical uses* of `unsafeCoerce` than about *typical uses* of `unsafePerformIO`. Typically, `unsafeCoerce` is used either to shift between a typed representation and an untyped one (where the user knows they have to track the types themselves), to state a reasonable axiom, or to short-cut the proof of a theorem. (cont)

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` *can* be used in a manner easily seen to be safe to perform a conceptually pure action in an impure fashion. For example, `unsafePerformIO $ fmap f newStdGen`, where `f` is a Las Vegas algorithm,is obviously safe. However, `unsafePerformIO` is also often used to maintain hidden state; in that usage it is extremely easy to screw everything up.

Comment: @dfeuer I mean if you are arguing about typical uses then honestly I would say I disagree. I'd say they are pretty equally unsafe, because knowing what things are "morally pure" to me is no harder than knowing what things are "truly bit-for-bit identical". Both can be violated in ways that you might not expect, for example making unique keys for separate values is often done by beginners with unsafePeformIO and is unsafe, and if `x` isn't monomorphic `x == unsafeCoerce x` might not even be safe (it might segfault).