# Haskell: How to write a type of function from a specific type to any type?

Tags: haskell, existential-type

In Scala, I could write the following `trait`:

```
trait Consumer[A] {
  def apply(a: A): Unit
}
```

And scala would **convert** whatever I want to `Unit`, i.e., it would discard the type. Equivalently, I could have said that `apply` returns `Any` and ignore the result.

However, in Haskell, if I defined the type as `type Consumer = a -> IO ()`, I wouldn't be able to pass an `Int -> IO Int` function, as `Int` isn't `()`.

There are two ways I know of solving this issue, but none are satisfactory:

1. Use `Data.Functor.void` at the call site to manual change `IO a` to `IO ()`. This is annoying as an API user.
2. define `type Consumer a b = a -> IO b`, but then every time I would want to use `Consumer` in a signature, I would have to carry the useless type `b`.

Is there any way to define the `Consumer` type as a function from `a` to "`IO Any`"? As far as I know, Haskell does not support something like `exists x. a -> IO x`.

Using `forall` results in the opposite of what I want, e.g.,

```
type Consumer = forall b. a -> IO b
foo :: Int -> IO Int
foo = undefined
bar :: Consumer Int
bar = foo
```

results in the error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘Int’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          bar :: Consumer Int
      Expected type: Int -> IO b
        Actual type: Int -> IO Int
    • In the expression: foo
      In an equation for ‘bar’: bar = foo
    • Relevant bindings include
        bar :: Int -> IO b
```

Note that I specifically want `Consumer` to a be `type` alias, and not a `data` constructor, as is described here: [Haskell function returning existential type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33063853). I wouldn't mind if `Consumer` were a `class` if anyone knows how to make that work.

Comment: Haskell doesn't have implicit type conversions of any kind. And this is a good thing. I personally consider this to be a deficiency of Scala, not an advantage. Consequently, everybody is ok with having to convert manually. Users of your API won't mind (unless they too come from Scala).

Comment: I'm the user of my API, and I mind.

Comment: @Gal in the point 2 of your question you say that `type Consumer a b = a -> IO b` force you to carry _useless_ type `b`. If `b` is useless, Can't you define it as `()`?. If not please edit your question to show a use case  :)

Comment: As I mentioned, defining the output type as `IO ()` forces my to use `Data.Functor.void` to discard the type at the call-site.

Comment: The usual option is to generalize the type of the function which "consumes the consumer", i.e. instead of `foo :: (a -> IO ()) -> ...` we can use `foo :: (a -> IO b) -> ...`. Alternatively, we could use an existential type as you propose, but those in Haskell require a constructor wrapper to be used, and that would be similar to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

To get an existentially-quantified type in Haskell, you need to write down a `data` declaration (as opposed to a `newtype` declaration or a type alias declaration, like you used.).

Here's a `Consumer` type that fits your purposes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Consumer input = forall output. Consumer { runDiscardingOutput :: input -> IO output }
```

And, analogously, here is what your example would look like with the new type:

```
f :: Int -> IO Int
f = undefined

g :: Consumer Int
g = Consumer f
```

This doesn't really avoid your concerns about client code needing an extra call, though. (I mean, this is no better than exporting a `consumer = Data.Functor.void` binding from your library.) Also, it complicates how clients will be able to use a consumer, too:

```
consumer :: Consumer Int
consumer = Consumer (\x -> return [x])

{- This doesn't typecheck -}
main1 :: IO ()
main1 = runIgnoringOutput consumer 4

{- This doesn't typecheck (!!!) -}
main2 :: IO ()
main2 = void (runIgnoringOutput consumer 4)

{- Only this typechecks :( -}
main3 :: IO ()
main3 =
  case consumer of
  Consumer f -> Data.Functor.void (f 4)
```

So it would probably make sense to have a `apply` function in your library that did the dirty work, just as there was an `apply` function in the Scala library.

```
apply :: Consumer a -> a -> IO ()
apply (Consumer f) x = void (f x)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wouldn't mind if Consumer were a class if anyone knows how to make that work.

You can *simulate* existential types for classes with an associated type family.

But Haskell doesn't allow ambiguous types in classes without using something like a `GADT` existential wrapper, so you would still have the type information there *somewhere*.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Consumer c a where
  type Output c

  consume :: c -> a -> IO (Output c)
```

`c` is necessary here to allow for the reconstruction of the type of `Output c`, so it is not strictly an existential. But you can now write

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, InstanceSigs #-}

instance Consumer (a -> IO b) a where
  type Output (a -> IO b) = b

  consume :: (a -> IO b) -> a -> IO b
  consume = id
```

This may not fit your use case, because there will not be a type signature that can express `Consumer a` in a truly existential way. But it is possible to write

```hs
... :: (Consumer c a) => c -> ...
```

(You could also make use of `FunctionalDependencies` here to clarify the class somewhat.)

Comment: Why is this preferable to my second option of declaring `type Consumer a b = a -> IO b`?

Comment: Because it makes it possible to write function signatures which accept `a -> IO _` as an argument by constraining to `Consumer c a`, since every such function has an instance of the class. This isn't *perfect*, because what you're trying to do isn't a Haskell-ism. It is preferable to explicitly require `void`, or otherwise be polymorphic over the type `b`.